# Angular Material 2 : How to put a fab button on top of the md-table at the bottom right corner?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have a md-table showing some records and a paginator below. I want to show a fab button on the table (the table of content would run under it).

What I tried? 
I tried `<a md-mini-fab routerLink="." style=""><md-icon>check</md-icon></a>` inside the `<md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort> </md-table>` tags , but looks like everything under `md-table` is scrapped out and the table rows are then rendered by the material2 Table component .

Is there a clean(without using a lot of CSS, while using only classes) solution for it? If not what is the CSS based solution?

Comment: where exactly in the table are you trying to put?

Comment: Above the table(z-index) , at the bottom - right corner .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code below meets the requirements but is pretty dirty to be called straight forward solution.

What i did while playing with position : fixed , margin , z-index and bottom was that i made a div just below the md-table (on the level of paginator).

```
<div style="z-index:5; position : fixed;display : flex; 
align-self : flex-end;bottom : 10%; margin-bottom : 68px;">

<a md-mini-fab routerLink="." style="margin-right : 14px;" (click) = 
"tShowAdu()"><md-icon>add</md-icon></a>
<a md-mini-fab routerLink="/main/create" style="margin-right : 14px;"><md-icon>add</md-icon></a>

</div>
```

[image]

Note : Would update the answer or Post a new one if a better solution is found.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the `md-table` and `md-mini-fab` inside a `div`. Then, you can use `position: absolute` to float to the button on top of the `md-table` and use `right` and `top` css properties to adjust the position of the button.

html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <a md-mini-fab class="custom-button"><md-icon>check</md-icon></a>
  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="margin-top: 50px">
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </md-table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.custom-button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RqmjE8ePlozDLmxRNajn?p=preview)

Note: Since you mentioned "the table of content would run under it" I added `margin-top: 50px` to the table to position it below the button.

Comment: Hi nehal this is not the right solution , position absolute would make the button be positioned from the top of the screen rather than inside the div . Try to add <br> tags just before `<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">` and you would know what i'm talking about :D

Comment: Though i've solved it by similar way would post the answer shortly . But doing a position absolute is not that pretty it is barely functional . Thanks for the answer though .

Answer (score -7):

Use `class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right"`