# Making an Angular Material 2 (Version 5.2.2) FAB stick in bottom right corner

Tags: html, css, angular-material, frontend, angular-material2

## **TL;DR**

I am workin on getting a FAB in angular to stick in the bottom right of a side menu. It works when I have a lot of elements and can scroll, but not when there is no scrolling. Here is a [link to a stackblitz to play with it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/side-bar-sticky-fab). Excuse some of the unorganization, I had to rip some stuff out and format it a little differently.

## **Problem and description**

I am working on making a side menu div and want a FAB on it like so:

[image]

And from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) I was able to generate something that works great and exactly how I want it when I have my menu is filled with a lot of mat cards. Here is a gif of how it looks:

[image]

But then the issue comes when there isn't enough cards to scroll, and the add button is just directly under the last card:

[image]

I want to always have that add button at the bottom of the side menu, but also for it to be sticky and stay there when scrolling is possible. From what I have seen there are ways to do it easily with older versions of Angular, but nothing I have seen has indicated that's the case with the newest version.

## **Code currently in place**

#### main.html

```
<mat-drawer-container class="container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened="true">
    <iaas-sideMenu></iaas-sideMenu>
  </mat-drawer>

  ... Content on other portion of screen ...

</mat-drawer-container>
```

#### sideMenu.html

```
<div>
  <div class="searchBar-div">
    <iaas-searchbar></iaas-searchbar>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iaas-sidecard *ngFor="let card of cards" [cardData]="card"></iaas-sidecard>
  </div>
  <div class="addButton-div">
    <iaas-addbutton></iaas-addbutton>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### sideMenu.css

```
.addButton-div {
  transform: translateX(195px); /* Bringing the button to the right */
  bottom: 5px; /* Ensure it's 5 px from the bottom */
  position: sticky; /* Sticks it in position when scrolling */
}
```

The button's component and folder's take care of its functionality and coloring as well as z-index, and I figured the best way to work this was to make the div the button is in essentially a sticky footer inside of the menu. However, I have not found much information on where I could be going wrong and have tried multiple things, but wanted to see if there was maybe something obvious I was doing wrong, or even just some general suggestions that could help since I am still a rookie with angular 2 and frontend in general 
(:

### **Edit**

When using `fixed` or `absolute` for the position the button will just scroll with the cards with the current structure I have. gif for visualization:

[image]

Comment: Can you create a fiddler/codepen of your code? that would be easy to debug.

Comment: This looks similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565156/angular-material-2-how-to-put-a-fab-button-on-top-of-the-md-table-at-the-botto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your button to stick permanent to its position, you should use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: sticky;`

You can read more about positioning [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

[Edit 1]: Above code do the trick but the problem was that if you put the button component inside the component which has to scroll, then the button will scroll too. I just removed that button from inside of that div and applied the CSS mentioned above. Kindly check the link shared in comments.

Comment: And that's what I tried at first, but then when that happens it ends up scrolling up with the cards. I added a gif of that behavior above @Inzimam

Comment: Can you share with me code? so i can look into it and find a problem. Just by looking into given scenario I can only guess. Thanks

Comment: you can use stackblitz.com for angular projects to replicate

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. That is very helpful. +1, I have added a stackblitz to the question

Comment: Here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/side-bar-sticky-fab-uesi6q
I'll update my answer with what was the problem in your code.